# Unable to fetch all the contacts from Android

Tags: android, cursor, android-contacts, android-contentresolver

I need to fetch all the contacts present on the android device. But when I query using the `contentResolver`, I get only the newly created contacts. Even though there are multiple contacts present on the device. Below is the query I have used to fetch the contacts. The cursor does not return all of them.

I have also observed one thing. If I go and edit the contact that is not being fetched, then that particular contact gets fetched. Help me get all the contacts present. Am I missing something?

```
String[] projection = new String[] { Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY };
            Cursor people = mContext.getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, projection, null, null, null);
```

Comment: any luck in finding the solution..?? i m getting the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
public class ContactActivity extends Activity {

Cursor cursor;
ArrayList<String> NameList=new ArrayList<String>();
ArrayList<String> PhoneList=new ArrayList<String>();


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, null);

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int nameIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DISPLAY_NAME);   
        int phoneNumberIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER);

        String name = cursor.getString(nameIdx);
        String phone = cursor.getString(phoneNumberIdx);    
        NameList.add(name);
        PhoneList.add(phone);

        System.out.println("Name is :"+name +" number is : "+phone);
        System.out.println("Name is :"+name +" number is : "+phone);
        System.out.println("Name is :"+name +" number is : "+phone);



    }


}
}
```